# extreme sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `A/C#` AS `A/C#`,
    `MyRef` AS `MyRef`,
    DATEDIFF('2017-06-30', `Date`) AS `Days`,
    `Dr` - `Cr` AS `Balance`
FROM
    `BERNIE`.`answer`
GROUP BY
    `A/C#`,
    `MyRef`
ORDER BY
    BINARY `A/C#`,
    BINARY `MyRef`,
    `Days`,
    `Balance`
```

Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bernie.answer.Date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Can make the error go away by including `Date`, `Dr`, and `Cr` in the GROUP BY.

I get the GROUP BY thing (well maybe..), but this seems extreme?

Update:
Adding the aliases of the calculated fields (`Days` & `Balance`) to the GROUP BY also runs gets rid of the error. Now I'm more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the GROUP BY altogether. It is not appropriate in this case as there is no aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to disable the only_full_group_by setting by executing the following:**

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

OR

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: Yes, I could maybe do that, but I'd like to think there was a very good reason for it to be in mysql.